# geodesics in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and intersection with planes?

Tags: differential-geometry

i have this question: let S be a surface in $\mathbb{R}^n$
what is the relationship between "geodesic" and "the intersection of S with a plane "
thanks for every answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I see, I am assuming $\mathbb R^3$ below.

If the plane is one across which the surface is symmetric, then the intersection with the plane is a geodesic. Otherwise you cannot be sure.

The main examples are with surfaces of revolution. One type is an equator. The more frequent type are meridians, that is planes that pass through the axis of revolution. For surfaces of revolution, one can often get qualitative information about geodesics of other, more complicated, types using Clairaut's relation.

If you have something not a surface of revolution, such as ellipsoid 
$$ x^2 + 4 y^2 + 9 z^2 = 36,  $$
then the three intersections with planes $x=0,$ then $y=0,$ then $z=0,$ all three being ellipses, are geodesics. All the other geodesics are quite tricky.